# Xcode: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) using NavigationStack

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

If you put path in a class, Xcode crashes (previews for ContentView do not work). At the same time, it works fine in the simulator and on a real device.
However, if the path is declared locally, then the preview works fine.
What could be the problem?

Incident Identifier: D05B53D4-857F-4EB4-8680-1B8863E1F114
CrashReporter Key:   8DA0FC80-00B5-C2B8-0E5D-7A5E35B53951
Hardware Model:      iMac20,1
Process:             TestNav [4567]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/0B0216EE-3A52-49F9-8B48-24854A30FD37/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4DE52BD9-69F8-4926-B9F5-6C383F6C42FA/TestNav.app/TestNav
Identifier:          com.xxxx.TestNav
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [2193]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.0B0216EE-3A52-49F9-8B48-24854A30FD37 [1888]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [681]

Date/Time:           2023-11-22 17:47:58.8289 +0100
Launch Time:         2023-11-22 17:47:58.2133 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 14.1.1 (23B81)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process: exc handler [4567]

My code (SwiftUI):

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
 
   var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) {
...
}}

struct TestNavApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Published var path = NavigationPath()

}
```

I declared the path locally and the problem went away. But what I need is the placement of paths in the class. If the path is declared locally, then the preview works fine.

```
enum SamplePath {
    //    case ImagePickerView, PhotoDetailView, ImageView, Translate
    case Translate, PhotoDetailView, ImagePickerView, ImageView
}

@State private var path: [SamplePath] = []

NavigationStack(path: $path) {
```

Comment: You aren’t showing any relevant code but are you injecting the model into the environment in previews

Comment: Looks like you're right, I didn't inject the model into the environment during preview. Can you tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: Similar to your App file just in preview

Comment: Best keep your view data in structs instead of objects